# $\sqrt{2^2} = 2$, $\sqrt{2^4} = 2^2 = 4$, $\sqrt{2^6} = 8 \neq 6$, $\ldots$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

In general, if $t \in \mathbb{N}$, when is it true that
$$\sqrt{2^{2t}} = 2^t = 2t?$$

I know of course that it is true when $t - 1 = \log_{2}(t)$.  Are there other (*more arithmetic*) conditions, for which the equation $2^t = 2t$ holds, for $t \in \mathbb{N}$?

It appears to be true when $t = 2^s$, for some $s \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: For $t\geq 3$, $2^t>2t$ as can be easily proven by induction.

Comment: When searching for and guessing at patterns, three data points is not nearly enough... having looked at just one more data point would have killed your guess by noting that $\sqrt{2^8}=2^4=16\neq 8$

Comment: Indeed, thank you everyone for your help!  I was considering Fermat primes earlier, and jumped when I saw this *pattern*.  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equality is true: $\sqrt{2^{2t}}=\sqrt{2^{t+t}}=\sqrt{2^t\cdot2^t}=2^t$.

The second holds only for $t=1$ and $t=2$. Indeed, define for $t\in\Bbb R$ $$f(t)=\cfrac{2^{t}}{2t}$$ and $$g(t)=\ln f(t)=t\ln 2-\ln 2-\ln t$$
Now,
$$g'(t)=\ln2-\frac1t$$

We see that $g'$ vanishes only at one point, namely $t=1/\ln 2$. By Rolle's theorem, $g$ has no more than two zeros, and hence the equation $f(t)=1$ can not have more than two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition:

$2^t \gt 2t$ for $t \gt 2,$  $ t \in \mathbb{N}.$

Proof by induction:

0)True for $t=3.$

1) Assume true for $t.$

2) Step: Show for $t+1.$

$2×2^t = 2^{t+1} \gt $

$2×2t =4t \gt 2(t+1)$.

Answer (score -1):

> my proof using differentiation

Let
$$f(t)=2^t-2t$$

> $$f(2)=2^2-2×2=4-4=0 \cdots  (1)$$

$$f'(x)=\ln(2) 2^t  -2$$

> $$f'(2)=4\ln(2) -2=0.772589\cdots(2) $$

$$f''(t)=(\ln(2))^2 2^t>0$$
$$\text{for }x\in R$$

> $$\text{.: f'(t) is an increasing function for }x\in R$$

$$\text{but }f'(2)>0$$

> $$\text{.:} f'(t)>0 \text{ for }x\gt2$$

$$\text{.: }f(t)\text{ is an increasing function for }x\gt 2$$

> $$\text{but }f(2)=0$$

$$\text{.: }f(2)\gt 0 \text{ for }x\gt2$$

> $$\text{.:}2^t-2t \gt 0 \text{ for }x\gt2$$

$$\text{.:}2^t\gt 2t\text{ for }x\gt 2$$